# PyQt5 installation issue in Anaconda

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda, pyqt5, failed-installation

I was trying to install PyQt5 in windows 10 from anaconda prompt.But I found following error:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install -c dsdale24 pyqt5
    Solving environment: failed

    UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
      - pyqt5
      - zstd
    Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I uninstalled anaconda and installed again. But same issue. Could you please suggest a workaround.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for installing PyQt5 from this source? The current latest Anaconda distribution standardly already includes PyQt5 (under the package name  [`pyqt`](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyqt)).

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was trying to install because I did not know PyQt5 was embedded with Anaconda. Anaconda website even confused me further. They said, you can install PyQt5 using  "conda install -c dsdale24 pyqt5"

Comment: The confusion to new users is understandable. The [Anaconda Cloud website](https://anaconda.org/) shows the [official Anaconda package repository](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/repo) (i.e. the repository maintained by the Anaconda Inc. company) as well as user-created package repositories. The package that you were trying to install initially is from one such user-created repository.

Answer (score 0):

```
Anaconda\Scripts> conda install -c anaconda pyqt
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25724491)