# Spyder won't start in cmd

Tags: python-3.x, dll, anaconda, pyqt5, spyder

When I try to run spyder (any version of spyder) in cmd I get the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bjwil\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\bjwil\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 186, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "C:\Users\bjwil\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 87, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtSvg  # analysis:ignore
  File "C:\Users\bjwil\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtSvg.py", line 14, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtSvg import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I do not get this error when run spyder in MinGW Git for Windows.  I have looked for a few hours but cannot seem to find answer to why.  I have the `python3.dll` and `python36.dll` extension from Anaconda3 in the Anaconda3 folder.  I also cannot uninstall PyQt5 (getting `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - pyqt5`) and reinstall using either `conda install -c dsdale24 pyqt5` or `conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/bpentz pyqt5`.  I get:

```
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - conda[version='>=4.6.7']
  - pyqt5
Use "conda search <package> --info" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I don't understand how you messed up your Anaconda installation like this, but to install pyqt5 you just need to run `conda install pyqt`, that's it. If you're still having DLL errors after that, I'd recommend you to remove and reinstall Anaconda again because you probably corrupted your current installation by trying to install packages from channels like `dsdale24` or `bpentz`.

Comment: thanks.  is there a reason it is on the Anaconda website here: https://anaconda.org/dsdale24/pyqt5

Comment: just did a new install.  Spyder does not open from cmd in Windows but it does open in Anaconda Prompt and MingW Git Bash.  This used to open in cmd and now it doesn't.  CAM-Gerlach says here https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6934 that because I have PyQt 5.9.X it can cause issues.  Is this why it won't open in cmd?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54014900/9987623

Comment: @BrianWiley, you said: `is there a reason it is on the Anaconda website here`. Anaconda.org is a public website, so anyone can upload packages there. In particular,  `dsdale24` packages are very, very old, before Anaconda (the company) created official packages for it.

Comment: @BrianWiley, you said `Spyder does not open from cmd in Windows but it does open in Anaconda Prompt`: this (most) probably means that you didn't add Anaconda's installation directory to your PATH environment variable. So there's nothing wrong with the current behavior.

Comment: I have added Anaconda to my Windows path because this was the only way to open python files from windows folder directly in Spyder.  I can enter `jupyter notebook` and `ipython` in cmd and it works.  The only things that don't work are `spyder` and `anaconda-navigator`.  I think its because there is some discrepancy between the PyQt5 and qtpy folders that both come with the standard Anaconda download for windows.  I get error `qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found` just like in CAM-Gerlach post above.

Comment: Actually nevermind.  There was some folder in my path that was causing issue.  It works after I moved Anaconda folders up in my path.  Now I just need to see which folder and file it was.

Answer (score 2):

`conda update --all` fixed the same issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

There may different reason for this problem. Sometimes it is because you forget to install spyder in the anaconda environment.

You can install Spyder from anaconda prompt by running

```
conda install spyder
```

Also, you can install spyder by going to the anaconda navigator.